# How does $\sin[(n-57)\pi]-\sin[(n-57)\pi/2]$ become $\cos[n\pi/2]$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm deriving the coefficients of a digital filter and I arrived to the expression

$$\frac{2}{(n-57)\pi}[\sin[(n-57)\pi]-\sin[(n-57)\pi/2]]$$

while the next step is supposed to arrive to

$$\frac{2}{(n-57)\pi}[\cos[n\pi/2]]$$

Can someone please explain me what trigonometric identity am I supposed to apply here?

Comment: See the [Sum-to-Product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities).

Comment: or here you can see it directly. assuming that $n\in\Bbb Z$, note that both sequences $\sin()-\sin()$ and $\cos()$ have period $4$; so if you verify it for the right four values of $n$ you're done...

Comment: Assuming $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, the first one is $0$ because all integer multiples of $\pi$ are zeros of $\sin$.  Then you can distribute the $\frac pi 2$ of the second one,  use the period of $\sin$ as $2 \pi$ to simplify , and then finally use the sine shifting to cosine when you are off by $\pi 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, the first one is $0$ because all integer multiples of $\pi$ are zeros of $\sin$, so we can ignore that one.

$$\sin[(n-57)\pi/2]=\sin[(n\pi/2-57\pi/2)]=\sin[(n\pi/2-28\pi-\pi/2)]=\sin[(n\pi/2-\pi/2)]$$$$=-\cos (n\pi/2)$$

This just follows from the period of $\sin$ being $2\pi$ and the formula $\sin(x-\frac \pi 2)=\cos (x)$.

The result follows as the negatives cancel.